# What is the Sixth Number?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I'm thinking of 4 real numbers, $a,b,c$ and $d$ (they need not be integers, or even rational). There are 6 products you can make by multiplying pairs of these numbers, namely, $ab,ac,ad,bc,bd$ and $cd$. I'll tell you what five of those products are, in no particular order:
$$
2,3,4,5 \text{ and }6
$$
What is the sixth product?

Small hint:

> You can do this without needing to figure out what $a,b,c$ and $d$ are.

This is a fun puzzle I found on the [xkcd puzzle wiki](http://wiki.xkcd.com/irc/Puzzles).

Comment: Is it 1 or 7???

Comment: Do a,b,c,d have to be integers?

Comment: They need not be, question has been clarified, though you solved it anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The six numbers can be split up into pairs such that the product of the two numbers in each pair is the same across all three pairs: $(ab,cd),(ac,bd),(ad,bc)$. The only two pairs of numbers among $2,3,4,5,6$ which have the same product are $(3,4),(2,6)$. So the sixth number must be

> $\frac{12}{5}$.

Nice quick puzzle :-)

Comment: would it be possible to find the four real numbers a,b,c and d?

Comment: @Craftsman That could make a good follow-up puzzle!